# How do I initialize all scenes at the start in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, transition

Whenever I want to transition to a certain scene, it takes a couple of seconds before the `SKTransition` even starts. Is it possible to have all scenes initialized before the game starts?

```
NewScene *newScene = [NewScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition moveInWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionUp duration:0.5];
reveal.pausesIncomingScene = NO;
[self.view presentScene:newScene transition:reveal];
```

I've tried this with `didMoveToView` as well:

```
@implementation NewScene
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if(self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    // Load a bunch of stuff like this:
    SKSpriteNode *menuButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"mainMenu"];
    menuButton.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2,self.frame.size.height/4);
    menuButton.name = @"menuButton";
    [self addChild:menuButton];
    [menuButton setScale:0.8];
    }
}
```

How can I make sure that my Sprite Kit game runs smoothly?

EDIT:
It turns out the problem was that I kept putting the main thread to sleep to fade out music. I've made all my audio methods run in the background and it works fine now.

Comment: Can you show what you replaced with the "Load a bunch of stuff" comment? You shouldn't have any issue with creating scenes when needed, and if you are, it's more likely that you should rethink the way you're processing data/loading assets. You can start by doing as much asynchronous processing as you can and [preloading textures](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTexture_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKTexture/preloadTextures:withCompletionHandler:).

Comment: @0x7fffffff - Edited my post. I've tried preloading textures (used another answer on Stack Overflow for this), but the result didn't change. I might've loaded the textures wrong in the new scene. Perhaps you could show me how to load textures in the new scene?

Answer (score 3):

A good approach is to load all resources asyncronously before `SKScene`'s initialization. Apple uses this approach in [Adventure game](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/BuildingtheWorld/BuildingtheWorld.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013140-CH3-SW1):

NewScene.h:

```
typedef void (^AGAssetLoadCompletionHandler)(void);

@interface GameScene : SKScene<SKPhysicsContactDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

+ (void)loadSceneAssetsWithCompletionHandler:(AGAssetLoadCompletionHandler)handler;

@end
```

NewScene.m:

```
@implementation NewScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if(self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    // Load a bunch of stuff like this:
    SKSpriteNode *menuButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[self menuButtonTexture];
    menuButton.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2,self.frame.size.height/4);
    menuButton.name = @"menuButton";
    [self addChild:menuButton];
    [menuButton setScale:0.8];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Shared Assets

+ (void)loadSceneAssetsWithCompletionHandler:(AGAssetLoadCompletionHandler)handler {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        // Load the shared assets in the background.
        [self loadSceneAssets];

        if (!handler) {
            return;
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Call the completion handler back on the main queue.
            handler();
        });
    });
}

+ (void)loadSceneAssets {
    sBackgroundTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"background"];
    sMenuButtonTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"mainMenu"];
    // etc.
}

static SKTexture *sBackgroundTexture = nil;
- (SKTexture *)backgroundTexture {
    return sBackgroundTexture;
}

static SKTexture *sMenuButtonTexture = nil;
- (SKTexture *)menuButtonTexture {
    return sMenuButtonTexture;
}

@end
```

Then just present `NewScene` from your `UIViewController`:

```
if (!self.skView.scene) {
    CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;
    // Here you can present some loading scene or splash screen

    [NewScene loadSceneAssetsWithCompletionHandler:^{
        NewScene *scene = [[NewScene alloc] initWithSize:viewSize];
        [self.skView presentScene:scene transition:[SKTransition crossFadeWithDuration:1.f]];
    }];
}
```